# Is there a way to convert an image to grayscale?

Tags: graphics

Is there a way to convert a colored image to grayscale both for printing as well as screen viewing through pdfLaTeX?

Comment: if you run the `latex`->`dvips`->`ps2pdf` sequence it can be done from within latex

Comment: @Herbert Thanks! I was  always sure there was a way but could not figure it. Also I still have the gut feeling that one could hack straight into the pdf.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would suggest using a tool like "convert" of the [ImageMagick](http://imagemagick.org/script/index.php) package (which is usually installed if you're running Linux, but is also available for Windows).

```
convert -colorspace gray originalfile outputfile
```

Comment: Of course, this is a preprocessing step, and not something done by pdfLaTeX as such.

Comment: exactly, I was looking for a way through LaTeX

Comment: There is no color ocnversion code inside pdftex, but if \write18 is enabled, you could hook the external conversion into the compilation process transparently. I assume the graphicx package manual will explain how that is to be done?

Comment: Unfortunately, `convert` only works with raster images. Used with PDF (or any vector format) it produces poor results.

Answer (score 10):

Just a note on this, in respect to Linux tools:

- `convert` can convert color (mode) of bitmap/raster images to grayscale (*it can also convert a pdf to a bitmap/raster image*)
- `ghostscript` can convert pdfs (that include images) into grayscale pdfs (*see comments in [graypdf.sh](http://sdaaubckp.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/sdaaubckp/single-scripts/graypdf.sh?content-type=text%2Fplain), though; there's problems with metadata*)
- options `monochrome` to `(x)color` for `pdflatex` will cause mostly text color (and, I guess, related vector objects) to be grayscale

So, basically there would be two approaches to generating a gray `pdflatex` document:

- `pdflatex` it in color - and then convert the whole document to gray using `ghostscript`
- Use `pdflatex` with `\write18`, and use definitions of commands that will generate grayscale image on the fly.

Note that even if converting the whole PDF, the process will not necessarily be straightforward (for more, see [Converting (any) PDF to black (K)-only CMYK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6248563/converting-any-pdf-to-black-k-only-cmyk)).

For the second option, there is an example of a `\includegraphicsRS` in:

- [Can pdflatex (or any tex package) automatically rescale included images which have been reduced in size? #5811692](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020175/can-pdflatex-or-any-tex-package-automatically-rescale-included-images-which-hav/5811692#5811692)

, which calls `convert` under `\write18` to generate resized versions of images; I'm guessing it can be relatively easily modified to generate grayscale images instead (*it may also be possible to force `convert` to return the image data through stdout - so it is directly embedded in the pdf stream, instead of generating an intermediate file; but I wouldn't know how to solve that at the moment*).

Anyways, hope this helps someone,
Cheers!