# Can \includegraphics be used to change an image color?

Tags: graphics, xetex, pdf, color

I'm including a number of PDF images in my document using `\includegraphics`.  I'm wondering if there's a way for LaTeX to adjust their color profile, hopefully the same way it can flip images upside down, resize, and crop, as here:
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Importing_Graphics#Including_graphics

Let me detail a little more my desired outcome, in case there's another way to achieve this:
The images are brightly colored---I'd like to reduce color levels, or possibly render them grayscale, and I'd prefer to not have to do external pre-processing, if this is possible.

I'm using XeTeX.

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3322/is-there-a-way-to-convert-an-image-to-grayscale

Comment: No, `\includegraphics` can't change the image color. You need to use an external graphic editor.

Comment: If all you want to do is reduce the brightness then you *could* overlay a translucent rectangle on the image.  It wouldn't be anywhere near as good as doing it in an external program, though.

Comment: @MartinScharrer I think your comment is an answer :-)

Comment: It's healthy to note that neither the image filetype (`.pdf`, `.jpg`, `.png`, etc) nor the engine per se have influence on `\includegraphics`, so the macro will behave the same for all cases.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

No, `\includegraphics` can't change the image color. You need to use an external image editor. The `graphics`/`graphicx` packages are more or less just interfaces which pass the image to the output driver, like `dvips` or `pdftex`. Therefore you are limited to the features provided by these drivers. Image manipulation is not part of these drivers and even if it would be very difficult to have an identical interface for these in `graphics`/`graphicx`.

For anything except resizing, trimming/clipping and rotating you need to use an external image editor. However, using PGF/TikZ you can place some overlays before and behind the image. If the image has transparent parts you could add a background color etc.

Answer (score 53):

(Importantly, this does not work with XeTeX.  I mostly tested using pdfTeX, but things also seem to work in LuaTeX.)

In a pdf file, colors of an included image can be affected by a `/Decode` array.  This is accessed via the `decodearray` keyword of `\includegraphics`.

However: this fails in some cases when the color model is cmyk; and this does not allow to change the color space from whatever color space the image has.  My impression is that changing the color space from within pdfTeX (i.e. turn grayscale to rgb, or rgb to cmyk, etc.) is impossible.

Grayscale is the easiest.  Say we want to reduce contrast and make the image overall darker.  We'll map black (0) to some dark gray (0.2) and white (1) to some lighter gray (0.5).  This is done using `decodearray={0.2 0.5}` (braces can be omitted).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics{example-image.jpg}

\includegraphics[decodearray={0.2 0.5}]{example-image.jpg}
\end{document}
```

For an rgb example we can use `hacker.jpg` from the ConTeXt examples.  For a cmyk example, create a copy of `example-image.jpg` with this color space; I used the `convert` command-line tool from `imagemagick`:

```
convert `kpsewhich example-image.jpg` -colorspace cmyk /tmp/example-image-cmyk.jpg
```

letting `kpsewhich` do the job of finding where `example-image.jpg` is.  Then, try

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics{hacker.jpg}

\includegraphics[decodearray={0.2 0.3 1 0 1 0.8}]{hacker.jpg}

\includegraphics{example-image-cmyk.jpg}

\includegraphics[decodearray={0.2 0.2 1 0 1 0.8 1 0}]{example-image-cmyk.jpg}
\end{document}
```

Note that for the rgb color profile the `/Decode` array contains 6 numbers, and for cmyk, 8 numbers.  Each pair of numbers describes the linear transformation to operate on the corresponding channel.  The first array thus imposes the amount of red, inverts the amount of green light, and puts lots of blue.

The second array should fix the amount of cyan, inverts magenta, puts lots of yellow, and inverts the amount of black ink.  It doesn't.  Why?  Looking at the pdf file, I note that there are two `/Decode` entries in the same dictionary, one of the form `/Decode[0.2 0.2 1 0 1 0.8 1 0]` and one of the form `/Decode [1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0]`.  The second entry takes precedence, at least on viewers I tried (perhaps this is mandated by the standard), and it inverts all channels (see below for why).  If we edit the pdf file to replace the second `/Decode [...]` by any other key of the same length (being lazy, I do `/Decode` → `/xxxxxx`), our `/Decode` array takes effect, and the result is as wanted.

Why is the second `/Decode` array there?  Well, there appear to exist two types of cmyk, with slightly different conventions on whether white should be all zeros or all ones, and pdfTeX is clever enough to detect things and insert the appropriate `/Decode` array: without it, (some?) jpg images in the cmyk color space would be displayed and printed with inverted colors.

Anyhow, I'm going to ask a question about how to avoid this second `/Decode` array, since editing the pdf file is not pretty.

NB: In general, it is better practice not to include the file extension in the argument of `\includegraphics`, but since there is a need here to know color spaces precisely, so I don't want to worry about getting a png instead of jpg, or whatever.

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to create a single-color vector image without an actual color, so that TeX sets the color? E.g. for symbols that are included as graphic but should change their color depending on the surrounding text …

Comment: @Tobi I don't know.  I would expect it to be possible for vector graphics (e.g., eps with no mention of colour might do the trick), but not for raster formats.  I may be wrong.  Have you seen Heiko's answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/65083/2707 ?  It seems to point in that direction.

Comment: Huh, bravo!  That's very interesting.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't saw the other answer. Looks like it answers my question – unfortunately it works only with `pdflatex` …

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch Can you do this also with pdfs? It seems that using `decodearray` with `\includepdf` does not work.

Comment: @Karlo: I suspect that decodearray only works with jpg and not pdf inclusion but I don't have time to investigate.  Please ask a new question linking to this one (and specifically to my answer I suppose), so that other people may see your question and help you.

Comment: I asked a [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/424320/can-i-remove-dark-background-pictures-in-a-given-pdf-file?noredirect=1#comment1061514_424320) about whether you can apply this solution to a pdf instead of a single picture.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch thanks for such complete answer! I am trying to colorize the drawing (i.e. the lines, not the transparent part, which I could colorize it) of the following image: https://web.whatsapp.com/img/bg-chat-tile_9e8a2898faedb7db9bf5638405cf81ae.png Since I don't understand how `decodearray` works, I am unable to change the black draw color to a gray one. This is what I want: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFjnP.png The gray color is `{222,219,214}` in RGB. Thanks!!

Comment: @manooooh Sorry, I won't have time.  Maybe ask a separate question referring to this one?

Answer (score 6):

Interestingly, for the vector graphics that I've tried it on, `\color` command actually changes all the black into whatever color was given.

Comment: This is supported by pdfTeX/LuaTeX only and only if the graphics does not contain color settings. This behavior can be overwritten by the option `resetcolor` for `\includegrahics`. Then `pdftex.def` calls `\normalcolor` before the image is included.

Comment: Interesting.  Then I suppose there is no way to change the other colors.  For instance, leave the black alone, but change the grey to red?

Comment: No. The PDF image is included as whole unit.

Comment: Could you please give an example code?

Comment: \color{blue} \includegraphics{line-art}

Comment: I tried this with .PNG and .JPG images, `\includegraphics` cannot change their colors (remain black).

Comment: No doubt; I would only expect this to work with vector graphics, not bitmaps

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this issues for jpg and was able to use the decodearray to achieve my desired results. Unsure how it works with pdf. It seems by setting all arguments, besides the first one to .5 the color is washed out. The first argument allows you to change the darkness. 1 gives you inverted and 0 is extremely dark.

```
\includegraphics[decodearray={.1 .5 .5 .5 .5 .5}]{img.jpg}
```