# Change color in finished pdf file

Tags: graphics, pdf, color

Suppose I have a finished PDF file, say a figure generated from some software, where the ink is black. I would include it in a document. Suppose I want to include it in a `beamer` presentation with black background.

Is there a way to configure the include so i can specify whatever is black should be displayed white? If not, what command line tools could I use to process the PDF file?

Comment: maybe pdftk can do help you.

Comment: To manipulate pdf documents (extracting parts, changing colors, etc.) I recommend Inkscape. which can open/import pdf documents page-wise.

Answer (score 34):

**Easy case with uncolored PDF and pdfTeX (unhappily very seldom):**

The PDF file contains some drawings without explicit color settings and
the image will be included by the pdftex driver of the graphics package.

The following file generates such an image:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[active,tightpage,floats]{preview}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\Huge\bfseries\sffamily
\setlength{\fboxrule}{2pt}
\fbox{Hello World}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

The following file includes the image (t.pdf) and changes its colors.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\pagecolor{black}
\color{white}
\begin{document}
\Huge\bfseries
\noindent
Some text.\\
\includegraphics{t.pdf}\\
Some text.\\
\textcolor{yellow}{\includegraphics{t.pdf}}\\
Some text.
\end{document}
```

> [image]

This trick does not work with other drivers, because the other drivers
normalize the color before the image is included. If pdftex.def is given
the option `resetcolor` then the color is set to `\normalcolor` during
image inclusion.

**Manual color fixes**

With some knowledge of the internals structures the PDF file can be fixed
manually. First the compressed page contents needs to be uncompresed, e.g.:

```
pdftk test.pdf cat output test-uncompress.pdf uncompress
```

Then the pages content streams need to be identified and the color operations
can be either changed or deleted (by overwriting with spaces). Best is not to
change the size of the object otherwise the file offsets of the objects in
the xref table needs to be updated. BTW, also PDF (or PS) use `%` as comment char.
Then the file can be recompressed.

Or the PDF file is converted to PostScript (e.g. with pstopdf from xpdf). Editing
is easier if changing the file size does not matter.
PostScript does not have a xref table. However, the detection of
the color operators can be more difficult, because often they are renamed or
hidden in procedures. Unlike PDF, PostScript is a programming language.

**Programs for processing vector images like Inkscape**

If the PDF file can be successfully imported in Inkscape or similar programs,
the colors could be changed there.

**Bitmap conversion**

As last resort the image can be converted to a bitmap image (ghostscript and other convertes). That means quality
loss because of pixel data. But many image processing programs should be able
to change the colors.

Generating inverse colors can even be done by a feature of the PDF format that
is supported by pdftex.def. Colors can be inverted via the `/Decode` array (except
images with indexed color spaces). Each
color component has then two float values inbetween 0 and 1.
Thus the number of color components must be known (Mono: 1, RGB: 3, CMYK: 4)

```
\includegraphics[decodearray=1 0 1 0 1 0]{rgbimage.png}
```

For example, the ghostscript device `png16m` can be used to generate PNGs for
this usage. More details are explained in the PDF reference. The options of
pdftex.def are shortly explained in the file itself.

Comment: If the pdf is to be edited, look for the `rg` (fill color) or the `RG` (line color) operator in the content stream in the case of RGB colors. The three numbers before the operand indicate the RGB values. For CMYK, the operators are called `k` or `K`, respectively, and the 4 CMYK color values precede them. (Was just in the same situation.)

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday, I have been fighting a similar problem: while `xelatex` of `TeXLive2018` was producing `PDF` files without hard-stored blacks, it turned out that `TeXLive2021` produces files with immutable blacks.  (This may be due to `xdvipdfmx`'s version change `20180217 → 20210318`.  This broke my usage scenario of  [my “Emoji-includer”](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82756/unicode-emoticons-with-pdflatex/399571#399571).)

The difference is due to the following change in the generated `PDF` file (with added spaces):

```
- q 1 0 0 1 72 -62.967 cm 0 G 0 g 0 g 0 G BT /F1 9.9626 Tf -72 64.65 Td[<1841>]TJ ET Q
+ q 1 0 0 1 72 -62.967 cm                 BT /F1 9.9626 Tf -72 64.65 Td[<1841>]TJ ET Q
```

inside a `stream` in a PDF object which is the content of every PDF object of `/Type /Page` (the page above contains only a glyph indexed by
[<1841>]).

### My work-around

After uncompression, run

```
perl -wpe "BEGIN{binmode STDIN; binmode STDOUT} s/(?<!\S)(0\s+[gG])(?!\S)/q( ) x length $1/ge" emoji-from-list-uncompress.pdf >emoji-from-list-nocolor.pdf
```

This follows — in general — the Heiko’s answer on this page
and sebschub’s comment on this answer.  However, we edit away `g` and `G` commands instead of `rg`, `RG`, `k` and `K` from this comment.

The editing command above may have a chance to be not specific enough.  In the file I can see, the `g`/`G`⸣s come in long groups.
So the command

```
    perl -wpe "BEGIN{binmode STDIN; binmode STDOUT} s/(?<!\S)((0\s+[gG]\s*?){2,})(?!\S)/q( ) x length $1/ge" emoji-from-list-uncompress.pdf >emoji-from-list-nocolor.pdf
```

may be much more robust.  It looks for at least 2 black-`g`-or-`G` commands in a row .(These `perl` commands are in Windows’ shell
syntax.  Change `"`⸣s to `'`⸣s on Unixy systems.)

**Warning:** the resulting PDF file is still uncompressed.  Without compressing it,
including it in other files increases their sizes (unnecessarily).  (Use the `pdftk` command in Heiko’s answer with `compress` instead of `uncompress`.)