# Problem of \includegraphics with Beamer

Tags: beamer, beamer-metropolis

The following commands

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Test}
\centering
\includegraphics{xxx.pdf}   
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

yields a result

[image]

by using `pdflatex`, which is not what I expect.

Basically, 'xxx.pdf' contains white background, and it looks fine (correctly displaying white background) with \documentclass{article}.

Is it possible to include xxx.pdf in this document without any changes on xxx.pdf?

Any comments and suggestions are very welcome. Thank you.

---

Updated:
xxx.pdf can be downloaded [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9tOT3KvYTnvd1EyVG9JcGZVWE0)

Comment: Can you please upload a copy of `xxx.pdf` somewhere so we can try ourselves?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/65083/51022

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange!

Comment: @Henri Menke Please follow the provide link above. Thank you

Comment: @Symbol 1 Thank you for the link, it is solved by \textcolor{white}{\includegraphics{xxx.pdf}}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "problem" is, that your image has a transparent background. Principally this is easy to remove with imagemagick:

```
 convert xxx.pdf xxxx.pdf
```

However as `metropolis` uses a very light background colour, this would look rather ugly, look at the slight boarder between the image and the background:

[image]

So I would use the background colour of the surrounding page:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}

\definecolor{myback}{RGB}{250, 250, 250}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Test}
\centering
{\color{myback}\includegraphics{xxx.pdf}}   
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The whole point of having transparent background for figures is the ability to easily include it in documents that a have a coloured background.