# Can I remove dark background pictures in a given pdf file?

Tags: color, pdf

Maybe a long shot, but I give it a try here. Correct me if it is not a relevant question.

Imagine that you have a given pdf file containing slides of a presentation with a dark background:

a) black background with white text

or

b) for instance blue background with black text

You want to print hand-outs of this pdf file, but you want to modify it in order to reduce ink consumption:

a) invert all the colours

or

b) remove the dark background.

I have found some posts about the removal of a background or watermark using Adobe Reader. I was wondering if there exists a way to do this using LaTeX?

**Update after comment by samcarter**

I had a look at [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29227/can-includegraphics-be-used-to-change-an-image-color). I have come up with following MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage[margin=0in]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics[]{figure.png}
\includegraphics[decodearray={0.2 0.3 1 0 1 0.8}]{figure.png}
\includepdf[decodearray={0.2 0.3 1 0 1 0.8}, pages = -]{file.pdf} %not working
\end{document}
```

It works for the file `figure.png` (a first test). But now I want to apply the colour change to each page of the file `file.pdf`. It seems that I cannot use the `decodearray` with `\includepdf` (as shown in the MWE), or that I cannot insert all the pages of the pdf using `\includegraphics`.

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65071/change-color-in-finished-pdf-file or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29227/can-includegraphics-be-used-to-change-an-image-color

Comment: I suspect that it should be possible using a "transfer function" ("TR or TR2 entry in a graphics state parameter dictionary").  Another option is to cook up something along the following lines (but I will resist the temptation to do it).  Include the pdf and add on top of it a 99% transparent layer in DeviceRGB color space in such a way that all colors have to be converted to that color space for compositing.  Use the "default colour space" mechanism to define a crazy mapping that maps colors in whichever way you want.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch Do you have a referece about `TR` or `TR2`?

Comment: The [PDF 32000 specification](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) mentions it.