# Convert a figure in black and white at compile time

Tags: graphics, conversion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can \includegraphics be used to change an image color?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29227/can-includegraphics-be-used-to-change-an-image-color)

Is it possible to include a color figure and export it in black and white, converting it at compile time?

Something like the following:

```
\includegraphics[blackandwhite]{myfigure.png} % Not working code!!
```

Comment: Sadly, it's not possible to achieve that with `\includegraphics`. I'm afraid you'll need to convert the images by hand with another tool, e.g, with ImagicMagick's `convert`. `:(`