# How to create a pdf from svg that can be colorized?

Tags: pdftex, svg, inkscape

This [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/181165/123423) mentioned that when using PdfLaTeX, One can recolor the blacks of an image to any color using `\color`.

The Goal: Create an image (preferably scalable(svg)) that can be color adjusted inside LaTeX.

So I created a small black svg vector image in inkscape and saved it as a PDF (with the "PDF+LaTeX", "PDF 1.5" and "use exported object's size" settings), but when I include it with color it stays black...

```
\definecolor{accent}{RGB}{0, 130, 240} %blue
\color{accent} \includegraphics[height=9pt,clip]{location}
```

So how do I make a svg image color adjustable in LaTeX?

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! Are there colour settings in your image?

Comment: How do I check that?

Comment: You should be able to read this in the svg file - it is just an xml format.

Comment: the only two properties that contain the word "color" in their name are      pagecolor="#ffffff" and bordercolor="#666666". Besides, why does it matter if my svg file contains color settings? I'm exporting it as a PDF, so shouldn't the pdf not contain any color settings? Also I tried to export it as PNG as well but that didn't work either...

Comment: The technique you are trying to use only works on figures without explicit colour settings.  It is overriding a default colour.  Colours are also specified in svg files by `fill` and `stroke` commands amongst other things.  You should adjust the colours outside of latex.

Comment: Another way to think about this: In general, the `\color` command only works at the time the object is created. It does not act on an object that was already created.

Comment: @AndrewSwann alright, so I set the fill and stroke to none, my svg now reads: style="opacity:1;fill:none;stroke:none;stroke-width:2.5;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1" 

But when I convert it to pdf and try to includegraphics it now shows nothing when I include it (makes sense since the color of the object is nothing) but what settings do I need then so I can adjust it in LaTeX?

Comment: @RobtA That makes sense, so how does one create an image without color settings? That can be included in LaTeX and color adjusted?

Comment: I don't know how to do that. I work with print (paper) books, where there is no need for vector artwork, since scalability is not useful. Instead, I create a raster image at exact size and resolution in a graphics editor (such as GIMP). The LaTeX color commands do not act on a raster image, only on text or text-like objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest an alternative approach to some of the comments:

Use commandline tools to edit the svg file, then import that using the [`svg` package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74693/28808) (which in turn converts to pdf using imagemagick).

You might for example (on linux or with cygwin on windows) use something like `sed -i 's/fill:#000000/fill:#ff00000' test.svg` to switch black to red.  From within pdflatex you can use `\immediate\write18`

In full:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{svg}

\begin{document}
\includesvg{test}
\immediate\write18{sed 's/fill:#000000/fill:#ff0000/' test.svg >test1.svg}
\includesvg{test1}
\end{document}
```