# Color an example-image

Tags: color, includegraphics, mwe

Is there a simple way to set the color for a (blank) example-image?

The naive way doesn't work:

```
\begin{figure}
\color{red}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
\color{black}
\end{figure}
```

I certainly don't want to have to create and store lots of colored example images and insert each individually.  It also makes it awkward being forced to store multiple copies for different document environments or futz with image file paths.

As background:  I will use this for categorizing and prioritizing figures to be inserted later (e.g., red = landscape photo, green = portrait painting, blue = computer diagram, orange = figure to be computed, yellow = figure to be purchased....).

Comment: If the image is grayscale… No, you just insert the PDF.

Comment: Hah!  As Henry Ford said to potential customers of his first Model-T:  "You can get it in any color you like... so long as it is black."

Comment: Duplicate? https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29227/4427

Comment: I adopted Ford's quote to warn our young basketball referees about their whistle: it can be any color you like, so long as it's black. And I point to the fact that most football (soccer) referees use a bright yellow one.

Comment: Your (potential) duplicate was useful, but not *quite* a true duplicate, I believe.  First, I'm not asking to change the color of an *arbitrary* image (as the linked question addresses).  Frankly, I was hoping there was a parameter on example-image (analogous to example-image-a, example-image-b, ...) that would support color changes.  I suppose there's no way.  But thanks for trying.

Comment: Wouldn't a rectangle of the appropriate color do?

Comment: @egreg:  Sort of... but I want to keep the colored placeholder within a traditional \includegraphics[]{} so I can easily replace example-image with (say) myPhoto.jpg.  (I do all my figure drawing in *Mathematica*, never *tikz*, but what would you suggest I include in your proposal?)

Comment: @DavidG.Stork: How about [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmLL4.png) as an option - thick border?

Comment: @Werner:  Sure... that would be an acceptable compromise.  But how do I implement that within \includegraphics[]{example-image} so I can then easily swap in or out a desired image, e.g., myPhoto.jpg?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork: I used `\fcolorbox{red}{red}{\includegraphics{<image>}}`. The amount of red is set by the length `\fboxsep + \fboxrule`.

Comment: @Werner:  Thanks, but frankly that may be just too awkward for broad use.  After all, I have tabular environments for arraying multiple images, of different dimensions and such and surrounding an image will disrupt the layout, or require more work than it is worth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This makes colored rectangles if the argument to `\includegraphics` is a declared color. In the part

```
\prop_gset_from_keyval:Nn \g_stork_ig_ratios_prop
 {
  red=3/4, green=16/9, blue=3/4, orange=3/4, yellow=3/4
 }
```

you set both the known color and the aspect ratio for the corresponding type of image (height/width).

Example of usage. The complicated code could well stay in a separate file that you `\input` and when all images are filled in you can remove the `\input` line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor}

% to be removed when the document has all the pictures
\NewCommandCopy{\originalincludegraphics}{\includegraphics}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\RenewDocumentCommand{\includegraphics}{O{}m}
 {
  \stork_ig:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \clist_if_in:Nn { Nx } { T,F,TF }
\prop_new:N \g_stork_ig_ratios_prop
\clist_new:N \g_stork_ig_colors_clist

\keys_define:nn { stork/ig }
 {
  width .dim_set:N = \l_stork_ig_wd_dim,
  width .initial:n = 8cm,
  unknown .code:n = {},
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \stork_ig:nn
 {
  \group_begin:
  \clist_if_in:NxTF \g_stork_ig_colors_clist { \tl_to_str:n { #2 } }
   {
    \keys_set:nn { stork/ig } { #1 }
    \stork_ig_fake:n { #2 }
   }
   {
    \originalincludegraphics[#1]{#2}
   }
  \group_end:
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \stork_ig_fake:n
 {
  \textcolor{#1}
   {
    \rule
     {% width
      \l_stork_ig_wd_dim
     }
     {% height
      \dim_eval:n { \l_stork_ig_wd_dim * \prop_item:Nn \g_stork_ig_ratios_prop { #1 } }
     }
   }
 }

% set the known colors
\prop_gset_from_keyval:Nn \g_stork_ig_ratios_prop
 {
  red=3/4, green=16/9, blue=3/4, orange=3/4, yellow=3/4
 }
\prop_map_inline:Nn \g_stork_ig_ratios_prop
 {
  \clist_gput_right:Nn \g_stork_ig_colors_clist { #1 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
% end of temporary code

\begin{document}

\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{red}
\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{green}
\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{orange}

\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you don't want fixed aspect ratios for the various colors, you can modify the code to calls such as

```
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{red:3/4}
```

where the aspect ratio is always height/width, but a single integer is allowed (with `/1` implied).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor}

% to be removed when the document has all the pictures
\NewCommandCopy{\originalincludegraphics}{\includegraphics}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\RenewDocumentCommand{\includegraphics}{O{}m}
 {
  \stork_ig:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \clist_if_in:Nn { Nx } { T,F,TF }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn { NV }

\seq_new:N \l_stork_ig_name_seq
\clist_new:N \g_stork_ig_colors_clist

\keys_define:nn { stork/ig }
 {
  width .dim_set:N = \l_stork_ig_wd_dim,
  width .initial:n = 8cm,
  unknown .code:n = {},
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \stork_ig:nn
 {
  \group_begin:
  \seq_set_split:NVn \l_stork_ig_name_seq \c_colon_str { #2 }
  \clist_if_in:NxTF \g_stork_ig_colors_clist { \seq_item:Nn \l_stork_ig_name_seq { 1 } }
   {
    \keys_set:nn { stork/ig } { #1 }
    \stork_ig_fake:xx
     { \seq_item:Nn \l_stork_ig_name_seq { 1 } }
     { \seq_item:Nn \l_stork_ig_name_seq { 2 } }
   }
   {
    \originalincludegraphics[#1]{#2}
   }
  \group_end:
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \stork_ig_fake:nn
 {
  \textcolor{ #1 }
   {
    \rule
     {% width
      \l_stork_ig_wd_dim
     }
     {% height
      \__stork_ig_height:n { #2 }
     }
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \stork_ig_fake:nn { xx }

\cs_new:Nn \__stork_ig_height:n
 {
  \dim_eval:n
   {
    \l_stork_ig_wd_dim
    * 
    \tl_if_blank:nTF { #1 } { 3/4 } { #1 }
   }
 }


% set the known colors
\clist_gset:Nn \g_stork_ig_colors_clist { red, green, blue, orange, yellow }
\ExplSyntaxOff
% end of temporary code

\begin{document}

\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{red:3/4}
\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{green:16/11}
\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{orange:1}

\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for all the effort!  But by sizes and ratios will be arbitrary (not some clean ratio like 3/4).  And now suppose I have myPhoto.jpg and want to replace it in the green location.  What do I do?  (Currently, I might have an \includegraphics[]{example-image} with special aspect ratio, or such, and merely replace example-image with myPhoto.jpg.). Oh... wait... let me study your solution more closely....  Regardless (+1) for steps in the right direction.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I'm not sure what your expectations are: if you don't know what image you're going to use, you don't know its aspect ratio either. Anyway, would something like `green:16/9` be an acceptable syntax?

Comment: Perhaps.  Most of my figures are set in tabular arrays, where I set the width of each figure element by some proportion of the \textwidth.  Example:  `\begin{tabular}{ccc} \includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{image1} & \includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{image2} & \includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{image3} \end{tabular}`.  I'd like to make (say) one of them a red {example-image} and later when I get the correct image simply replace `example-image` with `image3`.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Replacing `green:16/9` with `image3` would be as easy, wouldn't it?

Comment: I suppose so.  And seeing no better (smaller code) solution, I hereby accept yours.  Thanks for all your diligence.

Answer (score 1):

The following approach

- Adds the option `color` to the list of keys for `\includegraphics` (default is `red`);
- Assumes that your "substitute" image is given by `example-image`.

If you supply `example-image`, a box of colour `color` that matches the dimensions set with `\includegraphics` is placed. Anything other than `example-image` is set as needed (even with a `color` specification).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor,graphicx}

\makeatletter
\define@key{Gin}{color}{\def\Gin@color{#1}}

\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}% Remove \fbox separation
\let\oldincludegraphics\includegraphics
\renewcommand{\includegraphics}[2][]{%
  \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#2}{example-image}=0%
    \begingroup
      \setkeys{Gin}{color=red,#1}% Default color is red
      \colorbox{\Gin@color}{\phantom{\oldincludegraphics[#1]{#2}}}%
    \endgroup
  \else
    \oldincludegraphics[#1]{#2}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\includegraphics[width=3em,height=4em,color=red]{example-image}

\includegraphics[width=3em,height=4em,color=red]{example-image-a}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yep.  That works.  Thanks (accept).