# Color an Example Image but Leave the Default Drab

Tags: macros, graphics, color, includegraphics, examples

This post asks for an extension of Werner's answer given in [Color an example-image](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/576988/color-an-example-image).

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %
\makeatletter
\define@key{Gin}{color}{\def\Gin@color{#1}}

\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt} 
\let\oldincludegraphics\includegraphics
\renewcommand{\includegraphics}[2][]{%
  \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#2}{example-image}=0%
    \begingroup
      \setkeys{Gin}{color=red,#1} % Sets default color to be red
      \colorbox{\Gin@color}{\phantom{\oldincludegraphics[#1]{#2}}}%
    \endgroup
  \else
    \oldincludegraphics[#1]{#2}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother
% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering
  \includegraphics[width=20em,height=30em]{example-image}
  \captionsetup{labelformat=empty} \vskip 8pt
     \caption{\textbf{\scshape{\large (Default Red) Figure}}}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering
  \includegraphics[width=20em,height=30em,color=blue]{example-image}
  \captionsetup{labelformat=empty} \vskip 8pt
     \caption{\textbf{\scshape{\large (Specified) Blue Figure}}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

which produces the two figures:

[image]

[image]

QUESTION: Is it possible to modify the macro so that the original example-image appears if no color is specified to produce the figure? If so, how? The macro currently defaults the color of the example-image to be "red" if no specific color is indicated in producing the example-image.

Thank you.

Comment: @Simon Dispa The original (default) example-image resized according to the `\begin{figure}` `\end{figure}` specifications, but the original "drab" color of the default `graphicx` image when no specific color is specified.

Comment: Not sure I fully understand the question, but to use the default color you can specify `color=.`.

Comment: @Peter Grill I thought so too; but when I ran the code with `\includegraphics[width=20em,height=30em,color=]{example-image}` for the first figure, it produced an error.

Comment: Not `color=`, but `color=.` (note the ".").

Comment: @Peter Grill It runs (with Pdflatex) without an error using `\includegraphics[width=20em,height=30em,color=.]{example-image}`; thank you. However, it produces a solid black image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the default value to for example `none` and add an extra check for that:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %
\makeatletter
\define@key{Gin}{color}{\def\Gin@color{#1}}

\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt} 
\let\oldincludegraphics\includegraphics
\renewcommand{\includegraphics}[2][]{%
  \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#2}{example-image}=0%
    \begingroup
      \setkeys{Gin}{color=none,#1} % Sets default color to be red
      \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\Gin@color}{none}=0%
      \oldincludegraphics[#1]{#2}%
      \else%
      \colorbox{\Gin@color}{\phantom{\oldincludegraphics[#1]{#2}}}%
      \fi%
    \endgroup
  \else
    \oldincludegraphics[#1]{#2}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother
% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering
  \includegraphics[width=2cm,height=2cm]{example-image}
  \captionsetup{labelformat=empty} \vskip 8pt
     \caption{\textbf{\scshape{\large (Default) Figure}}}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering
  \includegraphics[width=2cm,height=2cm,color=blue]{example-image}
  \captionsetup{labelformat=empty} \vskip 8pt
     \caption{\textbf{\scshape{\large (Specified) Blue Figure}}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for posting this answer.