# How to Add (Transparent) Color to a Graphicx Lettered Example-Image

Tags: macros, graphics, color, includegraphics

This post is sort of an extension to the question posed in [Color an Example Image but Leave the Default Drab](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/631315/color-an-example-image-but-leave-the-default-drab/631423#631423)

Consider the code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\makeatletter
\define@key{Gin}{color}{\def\Gin@color{#1}}

\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt} 
\let\oldincludegraphics\includegraphics
\renewcommand{\includegraphics}[2][]{%
  \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#2}{example-image}=0%
    \begingroup
      \setkeys{Gin}{color=red,#1} % Sets default color to be red
      \colorbox{\Gin@color}{\phantom{\oldincludegraphics[#1]{#2}}}%
    \endgroup
  \else
    \oldincludegraphics[#1]{#2}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering
  \includegraphics[width=10em,height=13em]{example-image}
  \captionsetup{labelformat=empty} \vskip 8pt
     \caption{\textbf{\scshape{\large Red Figure}}}
\end{figure}


\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering
  \includegraphics[width=10em,height=13em,color=blue]{example-image}
  \captionsetup{labelformat=empty} \vskip 8pt
     \caption{\textbf{\scshape{\large Blue Figure}}}
\end{figure}


\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering
  \includegraphics[width=10em,height=13em]{example-image-a}
  \captionsetup{labelformat=empty} \vskip 8pt
     \caption{\textbf{\scshape{\large How to Color Shade, Say Green, Figure A?}}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

which produces the output

[image]

I would like to add some (green) color shading to the last image (`example-image-a`). However, when I replace `\includegraphics[width=10em,height=13em]{example-image-a}` with  `\includegraphics[width=10em,height=13em,color=green]{example-image-a}`, I get the same example-image-a as shown.

This is perhaps, not surprising, because if `color=green` worked in this case, I suppose the "A" with its associated lines might be obliterated.

QUESTION: Is it possible, and if so, how may I add some (green) color shading to the `example-image-a` figure so that the image is colorized, yet the A with its associated lines are still visible? Might this involve some sort of a colorized transparent veneer?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well basically you only have to place a semi transparent rule over the image:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,graphicx}

\usepackage{transparent}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=10em,height=13em]{example-image}\llap{\texttransparent{0.5}{\color{green}\rule{10em}{13em}}}
  
\caption{How to Color Shade, Say Green, Figure A?}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this very helpful answer.