# How to include, and colour, an SVG image?

Tags: pdftex, mac

I would like to use some icons that are not available in Font Awesome 5. The template I'm using uses `\color` to apply a colour to a font awesome icon, and it would be nice if the same command could be used to colourise an SVG image.

Here's my test document

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

% Packages

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}


% Document
\begin{document}
    \color{red}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{kotlin}
    \includegraphics{graphql}
    \includegraphics{go}
    \includegraphics{ts-logo-128}
\end{document}
```

And here's a screenshot of the resulting PDF.
[image]

In the comments, I've been advised to try following the answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/535771/36296), after using inkscape to generate a PDF from the SVG file.

However, when I run

```
pdftk kotlin.pdf output kotlin-unc.pdf uncompress
sed 's/0.0.0.[rR][gG]/        /g' < kotlin-unc.pdf > kotlin-final.pdf
```

I get `sed: RE error: illegal byte sequence`. I am uncertain how to fix this.

[Original SVG files]{https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1H6dSeMZq-AmV4mZ9cS7uFd1Qux-S0G0J?usp=drive_link}
[Inkscape exported PDF files]{https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/13lzL77KTuBDJOpI8uuV77T1P74CMvliT?usp=drive_link}

Comment: The problem is probably that inkscape is not in your path. However as the icon won't change, I would open them once in inkscape and safe them as pdf.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, would that allow me to change the colour of the icon in LaTeX? If so, how?

Comment: Sure! If the pdf has a filled shape without explicit colour, it will automatically adapt to the surrounding text colour (here a guide how to remove the explicit colour https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/535771/36296). If it has an explicit fill colour, you can use this trick: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/453338/36296

Comment: Can you share your .svg file so we can check if it has an explicit colour or not?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, I have a few SVG files. One of which definitely has colour. When I export the colour one as a PDF, I can use \includegraphics perfectly fine. But, I find that exporting some of the others seems to create a tiny image in a very large PDF, which seems to mean that rendering them in the LaTeX generated PDF gives me some blank pages. Should I make a whole new question focused specifically on these images?

Comment: Inkscape has an option to crop the page to the content (File->Document Properties).

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, I've edited the question to reflect the process you suggest, and where I'm getting stuck. I've also included a couple of Google Drive links, because you mentioned sharing the files earlier so they could be checked.

Comment: Are you on a mac? I can reproduce the error with mac sed. Installing `brew install gnu-sed` and then doing `/opt/homebrew/opt/gnu-sed/libexec/gnubin/sed 's/0.0.0.[rR][gG]/        /g' < star2.pdf > star3.pdf` worked fine for me https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVWdW.png

Comment: I am, and your suggestion solved the problem. This works beautifully. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You're welcome!