How to invert the color of an image
How can I invert the color of an image included via \includegraphics?

See also here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/722299/

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz The question and answer are indeed very close (and I somehow found a similar question to learn about decodearray), but they are hard to find when googling tikz invert color image since my use case is a specific but common use case… But actually I realized that latex invert color image directly points to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34110/is-it-possible-to-invert-substitute-the-colors-of-included-graphics/722299#722299 which is focused specifically on this question, so I'm fine closing this one.
