# Produce a monochrome (pure black and white) pdf using xelatex

Tags: xetex, color

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{orange}{RGB}{255,127,0}
\begin{document}
\textcolor{orange}{Hello!}
\end{document}
```

When I compile this document in `xelatex`, it produces an orange colored 'Hello!'

I want to produce a pure monochrome (black and white) document.

How do I get that done without changing the `\definecolor` or `\textcolor` commands?

Comment: Why do you want to do it with xelatex? For tools under Linux, see e.g. [Convert a PDF to greyscale on the command line in FLOSS?](http://superuser.com/questions/104656/convert-a-pdf-to-greyscale-on-the-command-line-in-floss); I'm sure there are similar tools for the other platforms. See also [Is there a way to convert an image to grayscale?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3322/is-there-a-way-to-convert-an-image-to-grayscale).

Comment: @gernot is it not more straight-forward achieving a monochrome PDF using xelatex?
If I was scanning something to produce a PDF, I would use the tools recommended in those answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Note this is fixed in current releases of the xetex.def graphics driver so the patch here is not needed**

The `monochrome` option (inherited from the standard `color` package, not needing `xcolor`) is supposed to work, as in the other answer, but `xetex.def` currently breaks that option, we should fix that.

this works

```
\listfiles % <================ to get list of used packages and versions
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[monochrome]{xcolor} % <=====================================
\makeatletter
\let\check@for@XeTeX@colorstack\relax
\makeatletter

\definecolor{orange}{RGB}{255,127,0}
\begin{document}



\textcolor{orange}{Hello!}
\end{document}
```

but make sure to remove the redefinition when you do want colour.

Answer (score 3):

Just add for example option `[monochrome]` to `xcolor`.

See the following MWE (see marked line with `<==============`):

```
\listfiles % <================ to get list of used packages and versions
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[monochrome]{xcolor} % <=====================================
\definecolor{orange}{RGB}{255,127,0}
\begin{document}
\textcolor{orange}{Hello!}
\end{document}
```

and the resulting pdf:

[image]

and my list of used packages including version numbers:

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
  xcolor.sty    2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
  pdftex.def    2016/07/10 v0.06j Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
supp-pdf.mkii
 ***********

 )
```