# Compilation: produce both color and greyscale pdf

Tags: pdftex

Is it possible to set up the pdflatex compilation command to produce two pdfs, one being normally colored, and the other in greyscale? This would be usefull for CVs, for instance.

Comment: Do you mean for images included with `\includegraphics` -- if so see [Is there a way to convert an image to grayscale?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3322/28808).  For coloured headings, rules and the like, most (all good) designs will fail gracefully when printed greyscale, i.e. they will appear in a visible shade of grey. This certainly works well in the default moderncv template that I use.  Colour graphics that print nicely in B&W are a good idea in general

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use two commands:
If you use the `xcolor` package to produce colors and your file is named `some-tex-file.tex`, you can produce the colored PDF with

```
pdflatex some-tex-file
```

But if you use

```
pdflatex '\PassOptionsToPackage{gray}{xcolor}\input some-tex-file'
```

you get the same document in greayscale.

This will not change any images you include. If you also want to use grayscale images, look at [Is there a way to convert an image to grayscale?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3322/is-there-a-way-to-convert-an-image-to-grayscale).