# Decolorizing an \Includegraphics Image -- Is This Possible with LaTex?

Tags: graphics, pdftex, color, includegraphics, changes

I am working on typesetting a book that has recently entered the public domain. It contains several pictures, all of which are in black and white. I have obtained all of them in B&W except two, which I have found in color.

I would like, if possible, using Pdflatex, to insert these two colorized images but have LaTeX display them in the PDF in black and white.

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width=7cm]{example-grid-100x100pt}
\end{document}
```

which outputs the colorized image:

[image]

QUESTION: How may the code in the MWE be modified in order to display the grid in shades of black and white?

Thank you.

Comment: no, just load the thing into any image editor and resave as greyscale

Comment: I am sure something could be done on the command line (possibly on the fly) as well: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3322/is-there-a-way-to-convert-an-image-to-grayscale

Comment: @David Carlisle I took your advice. I used Inkscape and it got the job done (eventually). There are probably better image editors to use, but it worked. Thank you for your comment.